# pyulog library Script 'ulog2csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: type-conversion, python-import, command-line-tool, px4

The pyulog Library states in its [documentation](https://github.com/PX4/pyulog#scripts) the following:

> All scripts are installed as system-wide applications (i.e. they be called on the command line without specifying Python or a system path), and support the -h flag for getting usage instructions.

After having installed pyulog using pip a try to convert a .ulg to .csv using the command-line script yielded the following error:

```
C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyulog>ulog2csv Test.ulg
'ulog2csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The same type of error occurs when trying to execute the other Scripts included in pyulog.

What I tried so far:

1. Restarting the PC
2. Re-Installing pyulog with pip
3. Adding the ulog directory to PATH-Variable
4. Executing the code using Visual Studio Code
5. Installation from Source

Execution through Visual Studio gave the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyulog\ulog2csv.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .core import ULog
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

At this point I'm out of Ideas, though I am aware that this might be a case of missing something in the documentation. How do I get the scripts found/executable from the Command Line?